# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (blogger)

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have a website in blogger : www.watiqati.net

When I use inspect element in Chrome I see this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[image: problem]

this is the code :

```javascript
};
_0x5efbx0["html"](_0x5efbx9)
}
, complete: function () {
    $(".cover .Post:not(:first)")["addClass"]("cov");
    $(".sided:eq(1) .Post:not(:first) .Snippet, .sided:eq(0) .Post:not(:first) .Snippet")["remove"]();
    $(".broadcast")["each"](function () {
        $(this)["find"](".current:not(:first)")["remove"]()
    })
}
})
} else {
    _0x5efbx0["parent"]()["remove"]()
}
});
$(document)["ajaxStop"](function () {
    $(".broadcast")["each"](function () {
        var _0x5efbx1a = 0;
        var _0x5efbx1b;
        var _0x5efbx1c;
        var _0x5efbx1d = $(this);
```

I don't know what to do. I tried deleting to add , ; { } ( ) the same problem.

Comment: That AJAX function directly above the line with the error is a bit of mess and really long but I'd say you're probably missing a }); there somewhere

Comment: given the partial code you posted (I mean, there's no `if` for a start!!), the answer is a pineapple

Comment: i have done the test with chrome (inspect element) .you can do it yourself in my website.so do you suggest to delete else ?

Comment: This is autogenerated code, and thus horrible to debug. What was the code generated from?

Comment: i don't have any idea about that.i've buyed this template from a freind.i found some problems but i resolved them .it's the only code whish i did'nt solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that the `ELSE` shouldn't even be there. When you strip everything out of  your AJAX success and complete methods your code looks like this:

```
$(function () {

   $["ajax"]({
     url: _0x5efbx2
     , method: "GET"
     , dataType: "jsonp"
     , success: function (_0x5efbx8) {

    }
    , complete: function () {

    }
 })
 } else {
    _0x5efbx0["parent"]()["remove"]()
 }
});
```

But that is only after removing a giant chunk of code so who really knows...

**EDIT:**
After seeing the full code it just makes it more obvious that you're missing the IF for that section of code that is showing the error.
That script block starts at line 804 with:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(function() {
   $["ajax"]({
       ...
```

And has the error at line 1130 for an `ELSE` that has no matching `IF` and appears after the closure for the ajax code. You need to figure out what `IF` was meant to go at the start or remove the `ELSE`.

Comment: this is the whole javascript code : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q_1avZGlo0LuHpx-Km512GbuRidjjiYO

the problem is her " } else {
    _0x5efbx0["parent"]()["remove"] "

what do you suggest ?and thank you for your help Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete.

Line 839, opening **for** loop:

```
for (_0x5efbxa = 0; _0x5efbxa < _0x5efbx8["feed"]["entry"]["length"]; _0x5efbxa = _0x5efbxa + 1) {
```

Line 1114, closing **for** loop,

Line 1116, closing **success** function,

Line 1127, closing **Ajax** request.

Lines 1128-1130, probably belong to a different/missing loop, and are causing errors now:

```
} else {
    _0x5efbx0["parent"]()["remove"]()
}
```

Line 1131, closing the anonymous **function** (remove it).

Now it probably will not work as intended, but the structure is correct so you can start debugging from there :)